# WCF: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, dotnetopenauth

I'm working on an WCF service that is secured by Oauth via DotnetOpenAuth.

Somewhere I've got a configuration error that's causing the error "The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed." in my code and I can't see to find a setup that works.

Works fine localhost to localhost but once I put it on my server (not on the domain) it fails from that server to itself or from localhost to the server.

I'm a little worried about some of the other solutions on this site as they seem to disable security. Mostly it's that they don't seem to work for me.

Provider:

```
   <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DataApiBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="OAuthServiceProvider.Code.OAuthAuthorizationManager, OAuthServiceProvider" principalPermissionMode="Custom" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="DataApiBehavior" name="OAuthServiceProvider.DataApi">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="OAuthServiceProvider.Code.IDataApi">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <add prefix="http://devel.nanaimo.ca/" />
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Consumer:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDataApi" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://devel.nanaimo.ca/NanaimoProfile/DataApi.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDataApi"
            contract="CodeServiceOauthProvider.IDataApi" name="WSHttpBinding_IDataApi">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Update:** Looks like OAuthServiceProvider.Code.OAuthAuthorizationManager Is not being called on live. It's instantiated but CheckAccessCore is never called. I have no idea why yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is just blind shot but `AuthorizationManager` is used to authorize users and it is called after authentication but you have your service configured with default `WsHttpBinding` - it uses message security with Windows authentication. Windows authentication doesn't work between computers which are not part of the same domain.

I would start with `basicHttpBinding` which defaults to no security (no authentication). If it works then you can think about what security do you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually just created a windows username and password with very little rights and hard coded the username into my library. Certificated could have been another answer but I never got them to work.